# Return all values or search query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a reporting website where there are several hundred stored procedures which output the data. I need to add searching functionality to this which I could do by adding the following HAVING clause as such:

```
HAVING @Search in (FirstName, LastName, CAST(EmployeeID as nvarchar(25))
```

Now, the only issue is that I can't seem to find a way to return everything with that having clause included. So the initial report doesn't display anything as expected because I don't have any logic that would display everything now. I was thinking maybe a case statement combined with this having clause might be the way to go but I can't seem to get any kind of case statements to work with this like I need. Any thoughts? Or do I just need to use two separate stored procedures, one for display of everything and one for the search.

Comment: `HAVING` is usually used to filter based on the result of an aggregation - would a `WHERE` clause work instead? What is passed into `@Search`?

Comment: @DStanley - The `@Search` variable is any text entered into a text box by the end user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you control the queries, then you can do something like:

```
HAVING @Search IS NULL OR
       @Search in (FirstName, LastName, CAST(EmployeeID as nvarchar(25))
```